# How to override layout file in custom theme in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, theme, overrides

I want to override **catalog_product_view.xml** file which is located in

`vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file.

I created below files -

```
 app/design/frontend/Test/sample/theme.xml  
 app/design/frontend/Test/sample/registration.php
 app/design/frontend/Test/sample/composer.json
```

app/design/frontend/Test/sample/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.sku" remove="true"/>
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: @PrincePatel - I have applied theme to one specific product. I am trying to remove sku from product detail page. But it is not getting affected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend reading the [Magento devdocs documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-overview.html) about working with the layout in Magento.

Make sure you understand the difference between [overriding](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html) and [extending](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-extend.html) layouts in a theme as described in these chapters.

Comment: I have followed the same but still getting the same error

Comment: Do you mean you've added the theme under the design configuration for a specific product?

In that case could you try to add 
`<referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />`
inside the "Layout Update XML" text field under the design tab of the specific product? 
I'm guessing that the theme is not registered, did you confirm that it appears in the theme table in your database?

Comment: I am thanking you so much. It was a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Vendor>/<theme>/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml
```

But it's not exactly an ovverride. You can write there only the new rules you need.

Comment: I want to remove some fields. How to exactly override layout file.

Comment: You can remove your fields in that file. For example:

<referenceBlock name="view.addto.compare" remove="true" />

Comment: but layout file is not getting called

Comment: So strange. Have you cleared the cache?

Comment: yes, I have cleared my cache

Answer (score 0):

**Make sure you have registered and selected your custom theme from `CONTENT->configuration`**

After selecting your custom theme you need to deploy static files by

> php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy

Then create `catalog_product_view.xml` at **`app/design/frontend/Test/sample/Magento_Catalog/layout`**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
      <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```

Now flush cache and try.

Comment: I have applied theme to one specific product. I am trying to remove sku from product detail page. But it is not getting affected.

Comment: I tried above solution but still no effect

Answer (score 0):

try this following folder

```
app/design/frontend/Test/sample/Magento_Catalog/layout/override/base/catalog_product_view.xml
```

after remove this in file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
     <page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
       <referenceContainer name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
</body>
</page>
```

Comment: layout file is not getting called

Comment: @jassi i have update answer check it

Comment: still its not working

Answer (score 0):

In app/design/frontend/Test/sample/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

Please add following content to remove only SKU from Product Detail Page.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">

    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.stock.sku" remove="true" />
    </body>
</page>
```